# record "new" has no field .. postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.fv
(
  producer text NOT NULL,
  version text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fv_pkey PRIMARY KEY (producer, version)
)

CREATE TABLE public.fv_parameters
(
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT f_parameters_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name)
)
```

I would like to update automatically `fv_parameters` when I insert something into `fv`. So I created a trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_to_subtables
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public.fv
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.insert_to_subtables();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_to_subtables()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO parameters values(NEW.producer || '_' || NEW.version,'producer');
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.insert_to_subtables()
  OWNER TO "PUBLIC";
```

However, it keeps giving me error:

```
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "producer"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO parameters values(NEW.producer || '_' || NEW.version,'producer')"
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong? Clearly my table `fv` HAS a field named `producer`, and I am inserting a new row to it, so it must contain a `producer` field?.. Any help please

**EDIT** Solved, but still not sure how, I just deleted all triggers (I had only 2 of them, but named equally, in different tables), and declared them again. Now it works

Comment: `fv.parameters` has one column, which is name, but in your insert statements you are inserting 2 columns.

Comment: That's because I don't understand what NEW is referring to.. Since the trigger is launched when I insert into FV, why NEW has  a `fv_parameters` fields?..

Answer (score 0):

I modified function to return a record - otherwise it would not work... belowe is mostly your code - no clamed error...

```
t=# CREATE TABLE public.fv
(
  producer text NOT NULL,
  version text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fv_pkey PRIMARY KEY (producer, version)
)
;
CREATE TABLE public.fv_parameters
(
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT f_parameters_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table parameters(a text,b text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_to_subtables()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO parameters values(NEW.producer || '_' || NEW.version,'producer');
    RETURN NEW; END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# CREATE TRIGGER insert_to_subtables
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public.fv
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.insert_to_subtables();
CREATE TRIGGER
t=# insert into fv select 'a','b';
INSERT 0 1
t=# update fv set version='2';
UPDATE 1
t=# select * from fv;
 producer | version
----------+---------
 a        | 2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I dont understand several things: what is `t=#` and `INSERT 0 1` as well as `UPDATE 1` .?

Comment: just skip those `t=#` - it is `psql` prompt, and `INSERT 0 1` is stdout of statement - you cna find it in output in pgadmin...

Comment: this doesn't work... Adding return statement doesn"t change anything, because error occurs before the execution gets any chance to get there

Comment: But indeed, when I tried this my code in psql shell it worked... So i guess I messed up something in DB..

Comment: yes - that's my idea - It is working in vanila empty db - so problem is not in code as is - problem is in relation names conflicts or rules mess or smth else